# Need help handling documents using dom4j

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Company cp17 = new Company();
        Person ps1 = new  Person("Barry","15900000000");
        Person ps2 = new Person("Andy","15800000000");
        cp17.employee.add(ps1);
        cp17.employee.add(ps2);

        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element companyElement = document.addElement("company");
        for(Iterator<Person> personIter = cp17.employee.iterator();personIter.hasNext();){
            Person nextEmployee = personIter.next();
            Element employee = companyElement.addElement("employee");
            employee.addAttribute("name",nextEmployee.name);
            employee.addAttribute("phoneNumber",nextEmployee.phoneNumber);
        }

        Document document2 = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element compnies = document.addElement("companies");
        //move cp17 to document2 as a child of companies.
        //ERROR companies.add(cp17);
        XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
        try{
        xmlWriter.write(document2);
        xmlWriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I creat two Document Object , now I want to move one Element and it's child Elements to another.How can i do that .Can anyone tell me, thank you.^_^

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard DOM method Document.importNode to bring content from one document into another. http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/dom/DOMDocument.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29

```
Element companyElement2= document2.importNode(companyElement, true);
companies.appendChild(companyElement2);
```

(Assuming that this line:

```
Element compnies = document.addElement("companies");
```

is supposed to read:)

```
Element companies = document2.addElement("companies");
```

Comment: Yes, dom4j supports standard DOM methods as well as its own wide-ranging extensions/alternatives to the standard.

Comment: For anyone reading importNode is not implemented in dom4j 1.6.1 (or earlier I guess).

Answer (score 1):

[Element.createCopy()](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#createCopy%28%29) is probably what you should use: